# gRPC assertion failed after gRPC finished executing

Tags: grpc, assertion, epoll, grpc-python, grpcio

I am using **grpcio version 1.48.2**

My application is essentially a collection of gRPC servers on different docker containers, with 10 max workers in the thread-pool.

Recently I started experiencing an Assertion Error which causes the gRPC server to shut down:

```
[E0218 1000 ev_epoll1_linux.cc:1142] ASSERTION FAILED: next_worker->state == KICKED
```

This error occurred right after a gRPC call had finished executing successfully. (it finished successfully, because I have a logger print at the end which indicates success.)

I tried looking deeply into the error, i also retrieved the actual function that the assertion failed on in the gRPCio source code:

(The assertion failed in line 1142~, which means it failed inside this function:

```
static grpc_error_handle pollset_kick(grpc_pollset* pollset,
                                      grpc_pollset_worker* specific_worker) {
  GPR_TIMER_SCOPE("pollset_kick", 0);
  GRPC_STATS_INC_POLLSET_KICK();
  grpc_error_handle ret_err = GRPC_ERROR_NONE;
  if (GRPC_TRACE_FLAG_ENABLED(grpc_polling_trace)) {
    std::vector<std::string> log;
    log.push_back(absl::StrFormat(
        "PS:%p KICK:%p curps=%p curworker=%p root=%p", pollset, specific_worker,
        static_cast<void*>(g_current_thread_pollset),
        static_cast<void*>(g_current_thread_worker), pollset->root_worker));
    if (pollset->root_worker != nullptr) {
      log.push_back(absl::StrFormat(
          " {kick_state=%s next=%p {kick_state=%s}}",
          kick_state_string(pollset->root_worker->state),
          pollset->root_worker->next,
          kick_state_string(pollset->root_worker->next->state)));
    }
    if (specific_worker != nullptr) {
      log.push_back(absl::StrFormat(" worker_kick_state=%s",
                                    kick_state_string(specific_worker->state)));
    }
    gpr_log(GPR_DEBUG, "%s", absl::StrJoin(log, "").c_str());
  }

  if (specific_worker == nullptr) {
    if (g_current_thread_pollset != pollset) {
      grpc_pollset_worker* root_worker = pollset->root_worker;
      if (root_worker == nullptr) {
        GRPC_STATS_INC_POLLSET_KICKED_WITHOUT_POLLER();
        pollset->kicked_without_poller = true;
        if (GRPC_TRACE_FLAG_ENABLED(grpc_polling_trace)) {
          gpr_log(GPR_INFO, " .. kicked_without_poller");
        }
        goto done;
      }
      grpc_pollset_worker* next_worker = root_worker->next;
      if (root_worker->state == KICKED) {
        GRPC_STATS_INC_POLLSET_KICKED_AGAIN();
        if (GRPC_TRACE_FLAG_ENABLED(grpc_polling_trace)) {
          gpr_log(GPR_INFO, " .. already kicked %p", root_worker);
        }
        SET_KICK_STATE(root_worker, KICKED);
        goto done;
      } else if (next_worker->state == KICKED) {
        GRPC_STATS_INC_POLLSET_KICKED_AGAIN();
        if (GRPC_TRACE_FLAG_ENABLED(grpc_polling_trace)) {
          gpr_log(GPR_INFO, " .. already kicked %p", next_worker);
        }
        SET_KICK_STATE(next_worker, KICKED);
        goto done;
      } else if (root_worker == next_worker &&  // only try and wake up a poller
                                                // if there is no next worker
                 root_worker ==
                     reinterpret_cast<grpc_pollset_worker*>(
                         gpr_atm_no_barrier_load(&g_active_poller))) {
        GRPC_STATS_INC_POLLSET_KICK_WAKEUP_FD();
        if (GRPC_TRACE_FLAG_ENABLED(grpc_polling_trace)) {
          gpr_log(GPR_INFO, " .. kicked %p", root_worker);
        }
        SET_KICK_STATE(root_worker, KICKED);
        ret_err = grpc_wakeup_fd_wakeup(&global_wakeup_fd);
        goto done;
      } else if (next_worker->state == UNKICKED) {
        GRPC_STATS_INC_POLLSET_KICK_WAKEUP_CV();
        if (GRPC_TRACE_FLAG_ENABLED(grpc_polling_trace)) {
          gpr_log(GPR_INFO, " .. kicked %p", next_worker);
        }
        GPR_ASSERT(next_worker->initialized_cv);
        SET_KICK_STATE(next_worker, KICKED);
        gpr_cv_signal(&next_worker->cv);
        goto done;
      } else if (next_worker->state == DESIGNATED_POLLER) {
        if (root_worker->state != DESIGNATED_POLLER) {
          if (GRPC_TRACE_FLAG_ENABLED(grpc_polling_trace)) {
            gpr_log(
                GPR_INFO,
                " .. kicked root non-poller %p (initialized_cv=%d) (poller=%p)",
                root_worker, root_worker->initialized_cv, next_worker);
          }
          SET_KICK_STATE(root_worker, KICKED);
          if (root_worker->initialized_cv) {
            GRPC_STATS_INC_POLLSET_KICK_WAKEUP_CV();
            gpr_cv_signal(&root_worker->cv);
          }
          goto done;
        } else {
          GRPC_STATS_INC_POLLSET_KICK_WAKEUP_FD();
          if (GRPC_TRACE_FLAG_ENABLED(grpc_polling_trace)) {
            gpr_log(GPR_INFO, " .. non-root poller %p (root=%p)", next_worker,
                    root_worker);
          }
          SET_KICK_STATE(next_worker, KICKED);
          ret_err = grpc_wakeup_fd_wakeup(&global_wakeup_fd);
          goto done;
        }
      } else {
        GRPC_STATS_INC_POLLSET_KICKED_AGAIN();
        GPR_ASSERT(next_worker->state == KICKED);
        SET_KICK_STATE(next_worker, KICKED);
        goto done;
      }
    } else {
      GRPC_STATS_INC_POLLSET_KICK_OWN_THREAD();
      if (GRPC_TRACE_FLAG_ENABLED(grpc_polling_trace)) {
        gpr_log(GPR_INFO, " .. kicked while waking up");
      }
      goto done;
    }

    GPR_UNREACHABLE_CODE(goto done);
  }

  if (specific_worker->state == KICKED) {
    if (GRPC_TRACE_FLAG_ENABLED(grpc_polling_trace)) {
      gpr_log(GPR_INFO, " .. specific worker already kicked");
    }
    goto done;
  } else if (g_current_thread_worker == specific_worker) {
    GRPC_STATS_INC_POLLSET_KICK_OWN_THREAD();
    if (GRPC_TRACE_FLAG_ENABLED(grpc_polling_trace)) {
      gpr_log(GPR_INFO, " .. mark %p kicked", specific_worker);
    }
    SET_KICK_STATE(specific_worker, KICKED);
    goto done;
  } else if (specific_worker ==
             reinterpret_cast<grpc_pollset_worker*>(
                 gpr_atm_no_barrier_load(&g_active_poller))) {
    GRPC_STATS_INC_POLLSET_KICK_WAKEUP_FD();
    if (GRPC_TRACE_FLAG_ENABLED(grpc_polling_trace)) {
      gpr_log(GPR_INFO, " .. kick active poller");
    }
    SET_KICK_STATE(specific_worker, KICKED);
    ret_err = grpc_wakeup_fd_wakeup(&global_wakeup_fd);
    goto done;
  } else if (specific_worker->initialized_cv) {
    GRPC_STATS_INC_POLLSET_KICK_WAKEUP_CV();
    if (GRPC_TRACE_FLAG_ENABLED(grpc_polling_trace)) {
      gpr_log(GPR_INFO, " .. kick waiting worker");
    }
    SET_KICK_STATE(specific_worker, KICKED);
    gpr_cv_signal(&specific_worker->cv);
    goto done;
  } else {
    GRPC_STATS_INC_POLLSET_KICKED_AGAIN();
    if (GRPC_TRACE_FLAG_ENABLED(grpc_polling_trace)) {
      gpr_log(GPR_INFO, " .. kick non-waiting worker");
    }
    SET_KICK_STATE(specific_worker, KICKED);
    goto done;
  }
done:
  return ret_err;
}
```

I don't have any good idea about how to debug it further, to understand what is going on here - I don't intend to change GRPCIO source code nor blame it, but could it be grpcio library bug?

Would love any help / advice/ some shed light on what is wrong with this assertion, why it happened? what could cause this?

Thanks so much in advance, Yves.

Comment: This is definitly not the answer but i'm working around things by setting the environment variable GRPC_POLL_STRATEGY to poll. Might help you out, might cause more problems